# Make others text div change size when one text div changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following text divs.

```css
.owners{
  margin: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
}
```

```html
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row owners">
    <div class="col-sm-3 text-center" style="background-color:lavender;overflow-wrap:break-word;">Owner</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 text-center" style="background-color:lavenderblush;overflow-wrap:break-word;">Owner</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 text-center" style="background-color:lavender;overflow-wrap:break-word;">Owner</div>
     <div class="col-sm-3 text-center" style="background-color:lavender;overflow-wrap:break-word;">Owner</div>
  </div>
```

or the following link: https://codepen.io/Lamdepzai123/pen/RJqPqq

When I edited the content of the text divs, the text will wrap around, making one div changes its size. I would like to know how to make the three other divs change its size according to that div.

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: By `size` you mean `height` correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this css:

```
.owners{
  margin: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
}
.text-center{
    display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}
```

And here is [the updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rZNEmR)

Answer (score 1):

Add this CSS ! i hope solved your issue.

```
.row{
    overflow: hidden; 
}

[class*="col-"]{
    margin-bottom: -99999px;
    padding-bottom: 99999px;
}
```